# Cant start wsgi through Nginx

Tags: nginx, wsgi, flask

At first:
When i started nginx i see errors in log:

```
unix:/root/project/flask_paramiko.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream
```

uwsgi.ini:

```
[uwsgi]
#chdir  = /root/project
module = wsgi:app

master = true
processes = 5

socket = flask_paramiko.sock
chmod-socket = 666
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true
```

wsgi.py

```
from flask_paramiko import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

uwsgi --socket /root/project/flask_paramiko.sock --wsgi-file wsgi.py:

```
unable to find "application" callable in file wsgi.py
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
```

/usr/bin/uwsgi --ini /root/project/uwsgi.ini works fine without any errors.

I don't mind where is an error.

Comment: `/root/` does not sound like a path you would typically want accessible to anyone other than an internal system user called `root`. Also, how exactly are you starting uwsgi (a systemD unit? a sysV init script? - the chdir parameter might actually be useful if your init daemon does not pass the directory)

Comment: Moved to different folder. Starting uwsgi via systemd unit.

Answer (score 0):

You are using two different options, one specifies just the *file* the other the *module*

> `--module=wsgi:app` works fine without any errors

> `--wsgi-file=wsgi.py` unable to find "application" callable

(there is not much difference between `--option=value` on cmdline and `option value` in the ini)

The literal `application` is just the name uwsgi defaults to looking for if you only pass the file name.
If you application is called `app` instead, well then say so on the command line or in the config.

Comment: Thanks. Solved this problem. Can i ask additional question?
My flask app serving a many "routes", do i need to create all of them in nginx.conf? 
or nginx have an easy way to serve it?

Comment: First ask yourself: *Do I need Nginx to treat different routes differently?* In any case, thoroughly read the documentation of your framework (sounds like *flask*) on what other considerations are important during deployment, there is more to this than just routes.